# Evaluating tree without having to build an interpreter (Python)

Tags: python, oop, tree, composition

Earlier this week I asked a [generic question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/400040/representing-mathematical-tree-structures-using-software-in-a-compact-manner) in a related SO community regarding constructing mathematical trees using OOP. The main takeaway was that the Composite and Interpreter patterns were the go-to patterns for this kind of application.

I then spent several days looking around online for resources on how these are constructed. I'm still convinced that I do not need to construct an entire interpreter and that a composite might be sufficient for my purposes.

From the other question I was trying to construct this tree:

[image]

Without using OOP, I'd probably do something like this:

```
import numpy as np

def root(B, A):
    return B+A

def A(x,y,z):
    return x*np.log(y)+y**z

def B(alpha, y):
    return alpha*y

def alpha(x,y,w):
    return x*y+w

if __name__=='__main__':

    x,y,z,w = 1,2,3,4
    result = root(B(alpha(x,y,w),y), A(x,y,z))
```

This would give a correct result of `20.693147180559947`. I tried to use the composite pattern to do something similar:

```
class ChildElement:
    '''Class representing objects at the bottom of the hierarchy tree.'''
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
    def __repr__(self):
        return "class ChildElement with value"+str(self.value)
    def component_method(self):
        return self.value
        

class CompositeElement:
    '''Class representing objects at any level of the hierarchy tree except for the bottom level.
      Maintains the child objects by adding and removing them from the tree structure.'''
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
        self.children = []
    def __repr__(self):
        return "class Composite element"
    def append_child(self, child):
        '''Adds the supplied child element to the list of children elements "children".'''
        self.children.append(child)
    def remove_child(self, child):
        '''Removes the supplied child element from the list of children elements "children".'''
        self.children.remove(child)
    def component_method(self):
        '''WHAT TO INCLUDE HERE?'''


if __name__=='__main__':

    import numpy as np
    
    def e_func(A, B):
        return A+B
        
    def A_func(x,y,z):
        return x*np.log(y)+y**z
        
    def B_func(alpha,y):
        return alpha*y
        
    def alpha_func(x,y,w):
        return x*y+w

    x = ChildElement(1)
    y = ChildElement(2)
    z = ChildElement(3)
    w = ChildElement(4)
    
    e = CompositeElement(e_func)
    A = CompositeElement(A_func)
    B = CompositeElement(B_func)
    alpha = CompositeElement(alpha_func)
    
    e.children = [A, B]
    A.children = [x, y, z]
    B.children = [alpha, y]
    alpha.children = [x, y, w]
    e.component_method()
```

I got stuck in the last line, however. It seems that if I call the `component_method` at the level of composite class instance `e`, it will not work, since the architecture is not built to handle adding two Child or Composite objects.

How can I get this to work? What should the `component_method` for my `CompositeElement` class contain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def component_method(self):
    values = [child.component_method() for child in self.children]
    return self.func(*values)
```

This will evaluate the child nodes and pass the values to the function of the node itself, returning the value.

Comment: Nice. It works. Is there a way to enforce that the number of children for each composite object be equal to the number of arguments provided in its respective component method?

Comment: There is a python module called inspect. It provides a function called getargspec. You can pass a function into the function and get information about the arguments.

Comment: I was looking for a more "structural" way to enforce it. That is without use of external libraries.

Comment: @user32882 `inspect` is part of the python standard library. What do you mean by "structural"? something that looks at the syntax of your `def`s? That's not how python works